# Inverted Screenshot rooted Android device

Tags: android, shell, adb, screenshot, root

I have the following code that takes a screenshot of my rooted android device.

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
```

My device is inserted into a case and is technically positioned in an inverted fashion. But now when I take a screenshot it appears upside down. Is there a way to take the screenshot and rotate it before it is sent to the sdcard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see yourself from the source of the screencap tool at

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/screencap/screencap.cpp

there is no built-in option to do so.

However, with a rooted device you have the option of modifying that tool to re-order the output data.

You also have the option of capturing the output in your java program, and re-ordering it there before writing it to a file.  Or of making your own native program to pipe through.

Finally, you could script some common tool such as imagemagick to do so on whatever system you are using to examine the results.

Comment: Chris: Thank you. So, you mean I can install a custom android build version with the modified screencap.cpp file?

Comment: You hardly need to customize the whole of Android - it might be most trivial to rebuild the program within an AOSP build, but likely you would only need to install the modified binary of that particular tool.  Or you can post-rotate it, either between capture and the storage file, or off-device.